# Convert unicode character in R to UTF-8

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have a list of strings, with unicode characters like `<U+00c9>`

When I try `Encoding(Luc TR<U+00c9>HAN)` I get `"unknown"`,
charToRaw of `Luc TR<U+00c9>HAN` gives me `4c 75 63 20 54 52 3c 55 2b 30 30 63 39 3e 48 41 4e`.

How can I get them to UTF-8? `iconv` doesn't work unfortunately...

Comment: So does your character value look like `x<-"Luc TR<U+00c9>HAN"` or like `x<-"Luc TR\U00C9HAN"`? It might help to include `charToRaw(x)` so we know exactly what you are working with.

Comment: Question updated, character value looks like "Luc TR<U+00c9>HAN"

Comment: Then you do not have a string with unicode characters. You have an ascii string with an attempt at escaping unicode character. See the duplicate answer for one way to extract the unicode escapes and turn them into proper unicode characters.

Comment: FYI, I added an answer to the duplicate question, for an alternative solution.